# Name for matrices with $a_{ij} + a_{ji} = 1$?

Tags: matrices, terminology

Do you know of any commonly used name for square matrices $A$ having the property that

$$ a_{ij} + a_{ji} = 1$$

for all $i,j \in \{1,\dots, n\}$, where $n$ is the dimension of $A$?

Comment: If no name exists, I recommend calling it a Van der Linden matrix.  Gary Larson (creator of The Far Side) jumped at the chance to have a species of louse named after him.

Comment: I dont know if there is a common name for these kind of matrices, but it is almost an antisymmetric matrix. Note that $A+A^T=\mathcal 1$, where $\mathcal 1$ is the 1-matrix (all entries are 1). If you need these matrices often, just give them a nice name you like :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strigiphilus_garylarsoni ;)

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't making that up! :)